Ordenar una Hoja Excel con VBA ME añade una línea vacía al final de la hoja
Ordenar una Hoja Excel con código  VBA ME añade una línea vacía al final de la hoja ordenada
Empecé utilizando este código, en el que nunca comprobé si se producía algo raro:
 Call arfeMes ' Macro asigna libro, hoja, columnas: çFchMes, çAtoMes,çNumMes en hMes 
 hMes.Sort.SortFields.Clear '                                                               
 hMes.Cells.Sort Key1:=çFchMes, Key2:=çAtoMes, Key3:=çNumMes, Header:=xlYes 

En este punto, antes de la siguiente línea de código, añade una línea sin datos al final de la hoja. Comprobado reiteradamente. Ejecutándola cuatro veces añade 4 líneas
Cambié el código por este otro:
Call arfeMes ' Macro que asigna columnas: çFchMes, çAtoMes,çNumMes en hMes                                                                        
hMes.Sort.SortFields.Clear 
hMes.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=çFchMes, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
           DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
hMes.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=çAtoMes, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
           DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
hMes.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=çNumMes, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
           DataOption:=xlSortNormal 

With hMes.Sort 
    .SetRange Range("A:AA") 
    .Header = xlYes 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom 
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin 
    .Apply  '                                   después de este punto falla 
'                Aquí, antes de "End With", añade línea sin datos al final de la hoja.                 
'                Ejecutándola cuatro veces añade 4 líneas
End With 

No encuentro ninguna razón que lo explique/justifique.
Alguna Idea?
Saludos
